# dynamic linking of word and excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, dynamic-linking

This is my first question and it would have been nice to include an image but it seems that I can't. I have seen some answers to my problem but they always seen to be in one direction. Excel->Word. However I want Word->Excel->Word as described below.

I have an excel workbook that draws a graph. Some of the input data is pre-calculated and one or two parameters are entered manually and entered in a table in the spreadsheet.

I want to do the following.

The graph and the data entry table are to be displayed in word. The table in Word is also part of the spreadsheet but must be displayed separately. I want to be able to enter the variables in the table in the word document. These values are linked to the excel sheet, the graph will be changed and the actualised version displayed in the word document. I have attached two images, the data entry able. The entry fields are those in green and an image of the resulting graph. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your pictures, so the following is theoretical.

1) Open Word

2) Insert Chart - this opens a instance of Excel which is directly linked to the Chart, which I'll refer to as `ExcelChartData` to avoid confusion.

3) Edit the range in `ExcelChartData` to match what you have in your Excel data workbook.

4) Link the ranges in `ExcelChartData` to the required ranges in your Excel data workbook.

Changing the values in your Excel data workbook will then change the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't get the site to work it keeps throwing me out. I'll try again tomorrow